# Clear cache of Download Manager programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-download-manager, download-manager, clear-cache

I have an Android app that has a feature of downloading files. After using the app for some time, downloading files not working.

I came to know after some research, after a **clear cache of download manager of the system**, downloading files work completely without any issue.

That means this solution works perfectly. But that doesn't mean application users have to do that to use the app. So I want to do that using code.

I need any solution that can clear the cache of Download Manager of the system using the code.

Here it is template code for downloading:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
context.registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, filter);

downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(url);

DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);

//Restrict the types of networks over which this download may proceed.
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);

//Set whether this download may proceed over a roaming connection.
request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);

//Set the title of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled).
request.setTitle(savedFileName);

//Set a description of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled)
//equest.setDescription("Android Data download using DownloadManager.");
//Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(download_path, savedFileName);

//Set visible and shows in the notifications while in progress and after completion.
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

//Enqueue a new download and same the referenceId
downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

// receiver
private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
        query.setFilterById(downloadReference);
        Cursor c = downloadManager.query(query);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            checkStatus(c);
        }
};
```

Comment: Share your code .

Comment: I edited the post with code.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: Not yet. I have to use 3rd party library for this feature